# How to speedup debugging on Azure Service Fabric?

Tags: azure, service, azure-service-fabric

Debugging an ASP.NET MVC application on the Azure Service Fabric platform takes a long time. How do I speed it up?

Comment: Can you include information about the latency, about the connection that you have and region in Azure where the Azure Service fabric is deployed?

Comment: are you talking about debugging on local cluster or the cloud cluster ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about cloud cluster debugging then that is going to be a bit slow process if you are attaching debugger to that cluster, in which case you should be relying more on your application logs to find a problem because you should try to replicate the problem in your local cluster first and debugging that locally will be much easier.

Now if you are trying to debug on local cluster then couple of things are important to speed up things.

1. Set your cluster to run in 1 node configuration rather than 5 node
   configuration.
2. Set your "Application Debug Mode" to "Refresh Application". To do
   this, right click on the fabric project in your solution and click
   on properties. you will see a window where you can set project
   properties, here you will see this option of setting "Application
   Debug Mode".

once you have done this then you can hit F5 and the debugging will be a lot faster. Also remember that you don't need to publish your application every time you make code changes, all you need is build and cluster will pick up changes and you can debug any time. one last thing to remember is that if you make any changes to your settings.xml or manifest.xml files you will need to publish in order for these settings to be picked up by the application.

Hope that helps.